# Inserting a select statement into a if statement

Tags: sql, t-sql

EXIT_PROC:

```
SELECT * FROM database.corpdb_10102014.dbo.retail_setup     
      WHERE class_of_trade = 'Fuel Center'
      UPDATE BATCH_MASTER_POS
```

I want to run the update only if the class of trade is a fuel center.

Comment: Your code snippet is not valid SQL.  It is unclear (to me) what you intend.

Comment: An `UPDATE` statement accepts a `WHERE` clause just like a `SELECT`. Can you describe better what your result should be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want something like this:

```
UPDATE database.corpdb_10102014.dbo.retail_setup    
SET BATCH_MASTER_POS = myvalue
WHERE class_of_trade = 'Fuel Center'
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you meen but if you want to check some value to be true and then performe some update try this.

If exists (SELECT 1 FROM database.corpdb_10102014.dbo.retail_setup WHERE class_of_trade = 'Fuel Center')
   UPDATE.......